# boost mpi isend tutorial does't work

Tags: boost, mpi

I run the isend tutorial of boost mpi. but it gives me the following error.

```
#include <boost/mpi.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/serialization/string.hpp>
namespace mpi = boost::mpi;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  mpi::environment env(argc, argv);
  mpi::communicator world;

  if (world.rank() == 0) {
    mpi::request reqs[2];
    std::string msg, out_msg = "Hello";
    reqs[0] = world.isend(1, 0, out_msg);
    reqs[1] = world.irecv(1, 1, msg);
    mpi::wait_all(reqs, reqs + 2);
    std::cout << msg << "!" << std::endl;
  } else {
    mpi::request reqs[2];
    std::string msg, out_msg = "world";
    reqs[0] = world.isend(0, 1, out_msg);
    reqs[1] = world.irecv(0, 0, msg);
    mpi::wait_all(reqs, reqs + 2);
    std::cout << msg << ", ";
  }

  return 0;
}
```

the error:

```
> ==================================================================================
=   BAD TERMINATION OF ONE OF YOUR APPLICATION PROCESSES
=   EXIT CODE: 11
=   CLEANING UP REMAINING PROCESSES
=   YOU CAN IGNORE THE BELOW CLEANUP MESSAGES
===================================================================================
YOUR APPLICATION TERMINATED WITH THE EXIT STRING: Segmentation fault (signal 11)
This typically refers to a problem with your application.
Please see the FAQ page for debugging suggestions
```

Could you please give me some information about this error. I can run all other tutorials correctly.
Regards

Comment: This is an error from MPICH to tell you that your program had a segmentation fault. It could come from any number of things. Usually, it's a problem with the application, but it's also possible that there's something wrong with your MPICH/Boost installation. Did you check if there is a core dump that you can use to take a look at things?

Comment: Looks like an error in the tutorial to me. The documentation is scarce but probably it should be `mpi::wait_all(reqs, reqs + 1);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I change the string type to double or int, it works. but it seems string type data does not work. buy the way, the sugesstion by Hristo lliev should be taken.